# PHP MYSQL checkbox search

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

I am working on a checkbox search. I'm new to PHP. I would appreciate it if someone could help me. Basically the user checks the options required, hits submit and results matching the checkbox options is displayed. The checkboxes have a value of M for Male and F for Female which matches the data in the MYSQL table.

So if a user checks checkbox 'Male' (see code below) all data with 'Male' that have a value of 'M' in the MYSQL table are returned. And any checkboxes not checked should simply be ignored as the user is only interested in the option 'Male' being 'M' (true).

To sum up I only need the search to take into account checkboxes that have been checked and echo which users that has been selected(more like filtering) through PHP.Any help appreciated. Thanks

the table looks like this :

```
id      name     address    gender    race
-------------------------------------------

1. 1    Lee      NY          M        French
2. 2    James    LA          M        Colombian
3. 3    Kashi    JAPAN       F        Japanese
```

and i have a form with checkboxes like this :

```
<form action="shortlist.php" method="post">
 <label for="sel1">Gender:</label>
 Male:<input name="keyword[]" type="checkbox" value="M"  />
 Female:<input name="keyword[]" type="checkbox" value="F" />
 <button name = "myBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-  default">Search</button>
</form>
```

SQL :

```
$sql="SELECT name, address,gender,race FROM talent1 WHERE gender = $gender'";
```

I'm suppose to echo something like this :

```
echo "<table width='100%'>\n";
//if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
//$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
//$muchneededid = $row["talent_id"];
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))   
        echo'<tr>'."\n";
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>Name</th>';
        echo '<th>Address</th>';
        echo '<th>Gender</th>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo "<td>{$row["name"]}</td>\n" . "<td>{$row["address"]}</td>\n" . "<td>{$row["gender"]}</td>\n";  
        echo '</tr>'."\n";
        echo "</table>\n";
        }
        else
        {
       echo "0 results";
       }
       mysqli_close($conn);
       }
```

Comment: there are _no_ checkboxes in your html. Do you mean `select-options`?

Comment: but basicly it would be smth like `if checkbox 'm' then add to sql "OR GENDER='M' "`

Comment: sorry, i pasted the wrong code.

Comment: now you loop through `$_POST['keyword']` - if value=M add `"OR GENDER=M"` to sql

Comment: show your sql now and we can give proper answer

Comment: I'm not sure if my SQL is correct or not. here is how it goes     $sql = "SELECT name, address, postcode, state, country, gender, officetel, talent_id FROM talent1 WHERE name LIKE '$gender'";

Comment: Why would you compare the `name` to `$gender`? It should be `WHERE gender = '$gender'`

Comment: Do you only have "F" and "M" in your database? I mean all the records either have "F" or "M" or you have more then these 2 options? What would be the difference between selecting both "F" and "M" and selecting none of them in the result?

Comment: as you can see in my table, I only have F and M. If I select both then it shows both Male and Female user. If i select F, it shows only female users. If I select M then it shows only male users.

Comment: I can only see a sample of your data in your table not all of it. And my question was, what if user select none of them, should he/she see no records or should see all of the records?

Comment: I can see some syntax errors in your code, But I think it's better for you to open a new question. Because your main question has been answered and each question can only have 1 accepted answer. Also answering questions like this in comments is somehow hard and unreadable. But, you have to move you `<tr><th>...</th></tr>` block out of(before) your while loop and also move your `</table>` out of(after) your while loop. You have an `else` after your while block, What does it do? So if you open a new question and explianing your new problem in it, Then SO members can post a clear answer for you

Answer (score 2):

given the information we've got it would be something like this:

```
<?php
//$_POST['keyword'] = array("M", "F");
$sql_addon = ''; // EDIT: this was one line below first, which of course created an 'undefined' error.
if(isset($_POST['keyword'])) {

    foreach($_POST['keyword'] as $k => $val) {
         $sql_addon.= " OR gender='$val'";
    }
}
$sql="SELECT name, address,gender,race FROM talent1 WHERE 1=1 ";
if($sql_addon) {
    $sql .= " AND (1=2 ".$sql_addon.")";
}
echo $sql;
// SELECT name, address,gender,race FROM talent1 WHERE 1=1 AND (1=2 OR gender=M OR gender=F)
?>
```

Those 1=1 and 1=2 might look silly, but it's (IMHO) the easiest way to generate that sql. 1=2 is there to create a falsy value, so that no records will be shown if none of the options are clicked.

Comment: Great, I was writing a comment about 1=2 part which you added it. Also I think you have to enclose `$val` in single quote since it's character...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm kinda lost at troubleshooting this Undefined variable: sql_addon on line 18
SELECT name, address,gender,race FROM talent1 WHERE 1=1

Comment: @struppy you can move `$sql_addon = '';` out side(before) the `if(isset($_POST['keyword'])) {` and then change this line: `if($sql_addon) {` to `if(!empty($sql_addon)) {`

Comment: @EhsanT Thanks that solved the issue. Can you please enlighten me on how to echo the fetched results?

Comment: @struppy first if this answer has solved your problem, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/345806) it and also give it an up-vote. But about your request, it really depends on how have you written your current code. If you can edit your question and add the related php code on how you are running your current query right now(are you using mysqli or PDO)

Comment: @EhsanT I have already cast my up vote,  however due to reputation below 15, the vote will not be displayed, it will only be recorded. I have updated my code, i'm using mysqli.